# Как на Flutter реализовать CSS фильтр

Tags: css, flutter, flutter-ui

не занимался вебом немного не понимаю что это за эффект.

Подскажите как реализовать это на Flutter

```
background: #BD87FF;
filter: blur(40px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовал виджет

```
CSSFilter.blur(
 child: Container(
  height: 150,
  width: 150,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
   shape: BoxShape.circle,
   color: AppColors.blurBackgroundColor,
  ),
 ),
value: 40)
```